# Multi Agent Systems on µC

Tags: c, embedded, agent

Multi-Agentssystems (MAS) are a widespread field. I am searching for MAS Solutions on µC embedded Systems. Mobile C (http://www.mobilec.org/) is such a platform but it needs Solutions with an OS. I want to know if there are MAS Solutions that work on Low Power Controllers without an OS. I dont care if these solutions have reduced abilities.

Comment: How low power? How much FLASH and RAM?

Comment: "Multiagent systems" is an interesting field, but a vague requirement. Can you give a use case of what you would want each agent to do?

Comment: This is maybe a gross misinterpretation of what you're asking but is this anything close? http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial

Comment: I want to create a net of controllers(which can host more than one agent) who control different devices. They have to communicate to solve Tasks. Like I said there are many Solutions out there but i don't find any for non-OS µC.

Comment: ROS.org is not exactly what i am looking for.